# Best/Quickest way to execute Promises in-parallel? (React)

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise, parallel-processing, fetch

Suppose I need to fetch data to create a card. What is the quickest way to get this data using promises? This is the current way I'm doing it:

```
  async function getCards() {

    const promises = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      promises.push(getCard(i))
    }

    const cards = await Promise.allSettled(promises)
    setCards(cards)
  }

  async function getCard(i) {
    const property1 = await getProperty1(i)
    const property2 = await getProperty2(i)
    const property3 = await getProperty3(i)

    const card = <div>
      <div>Property 1: {property1}</div>
      <div>Property 2: {property2}</div>
      <div>Property 3: {property3}</div>
    </div>

    return card
  }
```

For my purposes, I don't need Promise.allSettled, since I don't need to wait for all 10 cards to finish awaiting (I may just create a  component), I can render each one as they complete. But I'd still like it to be parallel/execute as fast as possible. What other options do I have there? And is there a better way to handle what I'm doing in getCard?

Comment: Do you have any actual asynchronous operations here?  What does `getProperty1()` do?  If not, there will be no parallelism because synchronous code is run in a single thread (unless you use webWorkers).  If you have actual asynchronous operations, please show us the actual asynchronous code.  Trying to use `Promise.allSettled()` will offer NO benefit unless these promises are monitoring actual asynchronous code.

Comment: Also, promises don't "execute".  Promises are simply a notification mechanism used by some other operation (usually asynchronous).  It is the other operation that executes and then tells the promise when it has completed and the promise then notifies other code of the completion.  While this is mostly nomenclature, it's also important to the overall understand of what a promise is and how you use it.

Comment: getProperty fetches a value from an API, where i is the ID

Comment: then show us that code

Comment: It's pseudo-code that I've written. Just suppose getProperty calls fetch or something of the like

Answer (score 1):

If `getPropertyN()` are indeed an asynchronous operation (such as a networking request), then `getCards()` will run all the calls in your `for` loop in parallel, such that they are all in-flight at the same time and it will generally reduce the end-to-end time vs. run them serially.

There are some other factors in play, such as what the receiving host does when it receives a bunch of requests at once.  If it only handles them one at a time, then you may not gain a whole lot.  But, if the host has any parallelism, then you will definitely see a speedup by putting multiple requests in flight at the same time.

Note that your `getCard(i)` implementation is serializing the three calls to `getProperty1()`, `getProperty2()` and `getProperty3()` which perhaps could also be done in parallel with something like:

```
const [property1, property2, property3] = await Promise.all([
    getProperty1(i),
    getProperty2(i),
    getProperty3(i)
]);
```

Instead of this:

```
const property1 = await getProperty1(i)
const property2 = await getProperty2(i)
const property3 = await getProperty3(i)
```

---

Another thing to keep in mind is that a browser (such as a `fetch()` call) will only make N simultaneous requests to the same host (where N is around 6).  Once you exceed that number of requests to the same host that are all in-flight at the same time, then the browser will queue the rest of the requests until one of the previous ones finishes.  The way it's implemented, it doesn't slow things down to do more than the max requests, but you don't gain any more parallelism after the browser's limit.  If you were running this code from a different Javascript environment such as nodejs, then that limit would not apply as this is a browser-specific thing.

Note, the key thing to achieving the parallelism is launching multiple requests to be in-flight at the same time.  There is no requirement that you use `Promise.allSettled()` before acting on any results unless you need to get all the results in order before you can process the results.

If the results can be processed individually as they finish and can be processed in any order, you can also write the code that way without using `Promise.allSettled()` such as:

```
 getProperty(1).then(processResult).catch(processErr);
 getProperty(2).then(processResult).catch(processErr);
 getProperty(3).then(processResult).catch(processErr);
```

---

Note: I also don't see any error handling in your code.  Any outside network request can fail and you must have some handler for rejected promises.

Comment: So is Promise.all essentially equivalent to running the requests in a for loop? I read else where that awaits in for loops ran serially instead of in-parallel

Comment: @greentriangles1 - `Promise.all()` doesn't run anything.  Your own code make the functions call first and then passes an array of promises to `Promise.all()`.  ALL `promise.all()` does is monitor those promises for completion.  Yes, it is true that `awaits` in a loop run serially, but that has nothing to do with `Promise.all()`.